# Ceiling Fan no power to lights

Tags: troubleshooting

OK here we go.  Remote only ceiling fan Emerson CF955BS Midway Eco model, would work but not the lights.  Bulbs were OK.  Voltage tester showed current in the wires of the bulbs housing but a fuse was blown.  Not sure why it was blown, could be a good reason for that.

Here is where I offed up.  Local hardware did not have the 1.25 amp fuse, so "for today" I used the next size up, 1.6 amp. I knew this was not the best approach but...!

When I inserted the 1.6A fuse I heard a sound.  Fuse still looks intact.  Now no power
to fan anywhere and fan no longer spins.

So I did I blow the receiver?  Capacitor? Not sure where to start...

Comment: Fuse still looks intact and is intact can be two different things.  Test the fuse.  You seem to have a short somewhere/messed up wiring.

Comment: it sounds like you blew more than the fuse, which typically fail quietly. Caps are a good place to start, but there could be damaged ICs and other basically irreplaceable parts. If your'e handy with electronics it _might_ be worth pulling out the PCB, tracing and replacing, but that can take a lot of effort for an uncertain reward; it might be easier to replace, much as I hate to say it.